# Using windll in ctypes on Windows 7 (64bit)

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

I would like to ask if somebody has similar problem like me and if there is any solution for this.

When I used Windows XP (32bit) before I have installed Windows 7 (64bit), I've used following program in Python 2.7.8 without any error:

```
from ctypes import *
kernel = windll.kernel32
...
```

When I run this sequence on my current version OS I've get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'windll' is not defined
```

Could somebody know where is the root cause of this error and how to fix this?

Comment: What does *only* `import ctypes; print ctypes; print ctypes.windll` show?

Comment: `>>> import ctypes`

work ok (no error)


`>>> print ctypes
<module 'ctypes' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.pyc'>`

Also seems to be working fine


`>>> print ctypes.windll

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'windll'`

Comment: sorry, I meant a script with only those 3 lines, not each line individually -- what does a script with those 3 lines show?

Comment: Following error appears:

`➤ python test_ctypes.py
<module 'ctypes' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.pyc'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_ctypes.py", line 4, in <module>
    print ctypes.windll
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'windll'`

Comment: `/usr/lib/python2.7` eh?  Are you using cygwin or something?

Comment: Could that be because of the `Program Files` now split into two folders, one for 32-bit applications, another for 64-bit?

Comment: No cygwin - installed Windows 7 (64 bit) without any virtualization.
Now I realized that I'm using Mobaxterm...

Comment: I tried to run it under cmd.exe - without any problems. It seems that the root cause is in mobaxterm.

Comment: FYI, if you're wrapping a C library to be used as a Python library, then you should be using `CDLL` and `WinDLL` instead of `cdll` and `windll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message appears while short script described in comments (proposed by jedwards) is run under mobaxterm terminal. When the script is ran in cmd.exe console, no errors appears.

Thanks, guys, for heads up...